# WooCommerce add data- attribute to view cart button on success message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, add-filter

I've managed to change the html markup of the **View Cart** button on success message so I could add `id="open_cart"` to it, but I also want to add a data- attribute such as `data-cart="open"` to the html output, however only the `id` is returned.

Any ideas on how to add a `data-` attribute to it?

```
function my_add_to_cart_message() {
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) :

    $message = sprintf( '%s<a id="open_cart" data-target="open-cart"  href="%s" class="button">%s</a>', __( 'Successfully added to cart.' , 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) ), __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ) );

    return $message;

}
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'my_add_to_cart_message' );
```

This is what the function above returns:

```
<a id="open_cart" href="http://example.com/cart/" class="button wc-forward">Ver carrinho</a>
```

The `data-cart="open"` is ignored. Simply annoying.

Comment: Yes so strange. I delete my answer…Maybe you could try to add this attribute with a little query script targeting a special class selector that you could add in your hook…

Comment: Well, that's it for now, I'll keep researching, perhaps I come with a solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick explanation as to why this is happening.

Take a look at the Woocommerce **success.php** template which is responsible for displaying the success messages.

```
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The **wp_kses_post()** function sanitizes the output of the **$message** variable by checking for allowed tags and attributes.

Here's your solution:

Add this snippet to your functions.php

```
function my_filter_allowed_html($allowed, $context){
    if (is_array($context)) {
        return $allowed;
    }

    if ($context === 'post') { 
        $allowed['a']['data-cart'] = true;
    }

    return $allowed;
}
add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html', 'my_filter_allowed_html', 10, 2);
```

You need to hook into the **wp_kses_allowed_html** filter and add your data attribute so that the **wp_kses_post()** function doesn't filter it out.

Comment: Wow! That seems promising. I'll give it a try asap! Thanks for the detailed explanation. This is on my to do list I since don't remember when :/

Comment: Hello, I would like to do this on my web site. I need to allow `base64 data URI` for img tag. I tried something like below but didn't work.

       ```$allowed['img']['data'] = true;```
       ```$allowed['src']['data'] = true;```